# startPanel with onclick joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

I'm trying to show and hide a div in Joomla  but doesn't work

This is the div I'm trying to hide

```
<div id="muestra" style="display:none;">
   <? php JToolBarHelper::editListX(); ?>
</div>
```

The I'm calling the javascript function

```
echo $pane->startPanel('<span onclick="mostrar(muestra);">Proveedores</span>','id_panel') ;
```

My javascript is

```
function mostrar(id){
if (document.getElementById){ 
var el = document.getElementById(id); 
alert(el);
el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none'; 
}
}
window.onload = function(){
mostrar('muestra');
}
</script>
```

the first time el=Object, but the second one is null and never takes a value.

any ideas?

Comment: is this for a slidedown panel or edit button for a component?

Comment: but if you click on the button, it takes you to another page so can you just set the other page not to display it?

Comment: no when I click on my tab (second tab), no on the button I want to show a div with the button

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

**HTML:**

```
<div id="muestra" style="display:none;">
   <?php JToolBarHelper::editListX(); ?>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
echo $pane->startPanel('<span onclick="mostrar();">Proveedores</span>','id_panel') ;
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrar(){
    if (document.getElementById('muestra').style.display == 'none') {
       document.getElementById('muestra').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
       document.getElementById('muestra').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer I try... but don´t work the <div id="muestra" > dont hide

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding *muestra* with apostrophes:

```
echo $pane->startPanel('<span onclick="mostrar(\'muestra\');">Proveedores</span>','id_panel');
```